# Dynamic batching and padding batches for NLP in deep learning libraries

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface, dynamic-batching

This is the usual way we train modern deep learning models for NLP, e.g. with Huggingface libraries where we have a fix length for the input no. of tokens/subwoords unit. https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/pad_truncation

In the follow example, we have 5 sentences of various length and all of them are padded to the max length set at 1024.

The first part of my question is with regards to GPU memory usage and pad, when we train a model with batches of data with padded inputs, **would the padded tokens hog up the GPU RAM**? Even if the model don't compute them since they will return zeros, it's still rather wasteful.

**Or does PyTorch / Tensorflow or other lower-level tensor libraries reoptimize the batch such that the pads don't take up memory? If so, any pointers to code/docs on this?**

[image]

There are instances where the batches can be ordered in a way to arrange batches with similar length to go together, esp. at the start of model training, e.g. https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/are-dynamic-padding-and-smart-batching-in-the-library/10404/15

Instead of doing padding, are there existing code for some sort of dynamic batching without sorting, **is there a way to keep an offset of all the input sentences EOS token and pack the batch into something that looks like this**:

[image]

**Are there examples of the above batch packing in other deep learning libraries? Or in native Pytorch/Tensorflow/JAX?**

Comment: There's this https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence.html that we seldom see in Transformers model. I'm not exactly sure why we're not using that though.

Comment: There's also https://github.com/pytorch/xla/issues/1522

Answer (score 2):

That is commonly called sequence packing, creating a consistent-sized data structure composed of different, variable length sequences. Sequence packing has the potential to speed up training by replacing filler padding with training data.

Sequence packing can can be done in PyTorch with [pack_padded_sequence](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence.html#torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence)  and in TensorFlow with [pack_sequence_as](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nest/pack_sequence_as).

Comment: Does that work for transformers or just RNN?

Answer (score 1):

Great questions!

When training a model with batches of data with padded inputs, the padded tokens will take up GPU memory. This is because the padding zeros are still being stored in memory, even if they are not being computed by the model. Therefore, padding can be wasteful, especially when dealing with large datasets.

However, PyTorch and TensorFlow both have optimizations to avoid this wastage.
Both PyTorch and TensorFlow have functions for packing and unpacking padded sequences. In PyTorch, the `pack_sequence` and `pad_packed_sequence` functions can be used to pack a list of variable-length sequences into a single padded tensor and then unpack the padded tensor back into a list of variable-length sequences. In TensorFlow, the `tf.RaggedTensor` class can be used to represent variable-length sequences and the `tf.ragged.packed_batch` function can be used to pack a batch of variable-length sequences into a single padded tensor.

Here's an example of using `PackedSequence` in PyTorch:

```py
import torch
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pack_sequence

sentences = ['this is a short sentence', 'this is a longer sentence that requires padding']

# convert each sentence to a tensor
sentences = [torch.tensor([tokenizer.encode(sentence)]) for sentence in sentences]

# pack the tensors into a PackedSequence
packed = pack_sequence(sentences, enforce_sorted=False)

# use the packed sequence in your model
output, hidden = lstm(packed)
```

Here's an example of using `RaggedTensor` in TensorFlow:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

sentences = ['this is a short sentence', 'this is a longer sentence that requires padding']

# convert each sentence to a tensor
sentences = [tf.constant(tokenizer.encode(sentence)) for sentence in sentences]

# create a ragged tensor from the tensors
ragged = tf.ragged.constant(sentences)

# use the ragged tensor in your model
output, hidden = lstm(ragged)
```

Using `PackedSequence` or `RaggedTensor` can be more memory-efficient than padding, especially when dealing with variable-length sequences. Additionally, as you mentioned, you can also use smart batching techniques to further optimize memory usage.

Regarding dynamic batching without sorting, one approach is to use bucketing. Bucketing involves sorting the sequences by length and then dividing them into buckets of similar length. The sequences within each bucket can be padded to the length of the longest sequence in the bucket, and the batches can be formed by randomly selecting a bucket and then randomly selecting a sequence from the bucket.

As for dynamic batching without sorting, there are existing implementations in deep learning libraries, such as `DynamicPaddingBucketingSampler` in MXNet,  `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` class in PyTorch supports bucketing and windowing, and the `tf.data.Dataset` API in TensorFlow supports similar functionality. There are also third-party libraries such as `torchtext` for PyTorch and `tensorflow-datasets` for TensorFlow that provide pre-defined datasets and data processing pipelines with support for dynamic batching.

There are also libraries that provide dynamic batching functionality out of the box, such as NVIDIA's TensorRT and Google's Lingvo. These libraries use dynamic batching and other techniques to optimize the use of GPU memory and improve training efficiency.

---

**References**

- [JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#Packed-Variable-Length-Inputs)
- [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence.html)
- [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/padding_mask)

Comment: Same question here, Does that work for transformers or just RNN?  =)

Comment: The cross attention limitations is kinda hard to "pack" when there's a dot product somewhere. So I'm not sure what it does in the Pytorch backend for that.

Comment: The techniques I mentioned for handling variable-length input sequences can be used for both RNNs and transformer-based models. In fact, these techniques are quite general and can be applied to any type of neural network that can take variable-length sequences as input.

Comment: Cross-attention in transformers can be a bit more challenging to handle efficiently than self-attention, as it involves computing dot products between sequences of different lengths. However, there are still techniques that can be used to optimize the processing of cross-attention.